# Restructuring to not use Exceptions by Determining which Method is Implemented

Tags: oop, reflection, dynamic, c#-4.0

So I'm developing something that works on `dynamic` variables using C# 4. And I'm in a situation where I have two variables `a` and `b` and I *know* that either `a.Foo(b)` or `b.Foo(a)` is defined. However I don't know which so at the moment I use something like this:

```
dynamic a, b, result;
...

try
{
    result = a.Foo(b);
}
catch
{
    result = b.Foo(a);
}
```

Which is horrible (not only is it inelegant but it's very slow since there is around a 0.5 probability of raising an `Exception` and producing a stack trace). I could use reflection but I expect that'd be quite slow too.

So is there a better way?

---

So that's the problem... but I'll also explain the context since I think there's a good chance there's a better way to handle the whole situation. Essentially I am building expression trees (using my own node structure) that work with many different datatypes.

If you consider the expression `1+'2'`, the `a` and `b` values are the operands `1` and `'2'`. If I want to evaluate the `+` node, which has the sub-trees `a` and `b`, then either operand may contain a method to `Add` the other operand's type to it. That is, either `a.Add(b)` is implemented or `b.Add(a)` is implemented.

I can only think of using reflection, the method above, or producing duplicate functions in both types of `a` and `b` to model the symmetry.

Comment: In a normal AST the operation "+" would be a node in the tree with a lvalue of (a) and a rvalue of (b), in which case your call tree would resolve to plusNode.Result(), where result would basically be a.Result() + b.Result(). Before I answered formally, did I miss something in your design?

Comment: Syntax note: That should be `catch { result = b.Foo(a); }`, without declaring an unneeded variable.

Comment: That's roughly it. Except each node has a List of values (which may be trees or values) instead of a lvalue and rvalue. And I should note that the tree is meant to deal with many datatypes.

Comment: It should probably be noted to that your example does not take into account reflexivity. a.Add(b) =/= b.Add(a)

Comment: GrayWizardx, very good point! You can assume that a.Foo(b) and b.Foo(a) should, if implemented, be equal.

Comment: Is this actually a performance bottleneck in your code?  Profile and find out!  Possibly comment the code saying along the lines of "throwing an exception is slow, but it works..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (like Ed said) I would resolve this by using a Interface (i.e. IResolve), which is applied to each of the nodes in your hierarchy:

```
Interface IResolve {
   IResolve Resolve();
   object Value { get; }
   bool IsResolved { get; }
}

class Add : IResolve {
   List<IResolve> entities;

   protected IResolve doMyAddLogic(IResolve lvalue, IResolve rvalue) {
       return new ResolvedNodeValue(lvalue.Value + rvalue.Value);
   }

   public IResolve Resolve() {
      IResolve result = null;

      foreach(var child in entities) { 
         result = doMyAddLogic(result, child.Resolve());
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

The problem is that you will have ambiguity with the resolution being behind an Interface. Its not perfect, and I dont like the lack of formal language notation (i.e. determinism of the tree), but it might be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft would recommend that you do it by providing an `IsImplemented` property or method, which you should be able to call to determine which of your objects implements `Foo` before calling one of them, only to find that it doesn't.

The overhead of exception handling isn't *huge*, but it is noticeable, and you should really avoid exceptions unless you're handling an exceptional scenario. This is a major difference between exceptions and error codes from C/C++.

So, add an `IsFooImplemented` property or something like that. It'll save you an exception.

Comment: The problem is that a.Foo might be implemented but simply not support b's type.

Comment: So provide a method IsFooImplemented(Type targetType). It's hard to give you a good answer without a more in-depth description of what you're doing and what your classes look like.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting *both* operands to a proper number before trying to add them?

I.e., use something like `System.Convert` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648195/c-dynamic-type-conversions), then:

```
dynamic a2 = DoConvertToInteger(a);
dynamic b2 = DoConvertToInteger(b);

result = a2 + b2;
```

Comment: I can't do that since '2'+'2' = '22'.

Comment: This doesnt necessarily solve the root problem, where a & b could be any types that need to be resolved before the operation proceeds. Consider if a was a subtree of (x+y) and b was null. The language semantics would dictate whether that resolution was correct (i.e. if x + y was a number it would not work, but if x + y where two strings, that operation is fine: (x => "x") + (y => "y") + null = "xy").