# Any built in object.AsType<T>

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have an input string such as

```
"x=y|a=b|c=10" etc
```

which gets converted to dynamic which i use as

```
dynamic d = getDynamicFromStringAbove();

someFunc( d.a.AsType<int>() )
```

where AsType is an extension method defined as

```
   public static T AsType<T>(this string o){
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
    }
```

QUESTION - Is there anything in the framework which provides this already

```
        object.AsType<T>()
```

?? It seems pretty handy with dynamic types so i am guessing it's there and i don't want to add code which already exists

Comment: @gdoron  apologies, updated Q above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no built-in method that works like your extension method. I think the framework designers wanted people to know that an explicit operation has to be performed to parse a string to an int, etc.

BTW, might I suggest changing your `AsType` method to use a `TypeConverter` instead of `Convert.ChangeType`? It's a little more powerful and flexible. For example, it works better for converting enum values to their respective types.

```
public enum Foo {A,B,C}
...

TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Foo)).ConvertFrom("A"); // Yields Foo.A
Convert.ChangeType("A", typeof(Foo));                      // Throws exception
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648256/120955) for more info.

#### Update

I should point out:

1. This approach really only makes sense if your `.AsType()` method takes an `object` as its parameter. As it stands in the question you are taking a `string`, and in what way is `s.AsType<int>()` preferable to `int.Parse(s)`?
2. Since you cannot use extension method syntax on a `dynamic` value, the code provided in the question won't actually work without casting `d.a` to a string value.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword, although it works only for references types.

You'd write an expression like:

```
var instanceOfT = a as T;
```

If `a` can be converted to `T` then it will contain a valid strongly typed reference of that type. Otherwise `a` will be a `null` reference.

Further examples of what you can and can't do with `as`...

```
dynamic d;

d = "test!";
// this will work and get a valid String reference
var stringInstance = d as String;

d = 1;
// next line generates a compiler error as Int32 (int) isn't a reference type
var integerInstance = d as Int32;
// and this compiles, but results in a null reference as d isn't a String anymore
var anotherString = d as String;
```

Comment: per the example in the Q cannot assume ref types only

Comment: @Kumar You could *cheat*, in a sense, by using `d as Int32?`. This may actually be preferable if the type happens not to be of the value type you're trying to convert it to.

Comment: The problem is, the data that he's trying to convert *won't be* an integer. It will be a string, and he wants it to be *converted to* the given type, not just *cast as* that type.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior If that's the case, then the use of `dynamic` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Yeah, the whole `dynamic` thing doesn't make sense anyway, since you can't use extension method syntax off of a `dynamic` value anyway. But I think he intended to have the extension method take an `object` as its parameter, and be able to call `.AsType<int>()` or `.AsType<double>()` or any other type that the given object could potentially be converted to, without worrying so much what the object's type actually *is*.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be a reference type. You can write `var integerInstance = d as Int32?;` and it works just fine.

Comment: @Timwi It does have to be a reference type, and `Int32?` *is* a reference type. It's alternate syntax for `Nullable<Int32>`.

Comment: @Yuck: No, `Nullable<T>` is still a value type. You can see that easily if you [tell VS to colour value types differently](http://ej.uz/ov9v) or by [pressing F12 on the word “Nullable”](http://bit.ly/GEcWih) or by [reading the documentation for `Nullable<T>`](http://goo.gl/4JXEP). (The [documentation on the `as` operator](http://is.gd/zFH76T) *incorrectly* states that the type must be “a reference type”, but *correctly* states that it “only performs reference conversions **and boxing conversions”**.)

Comment: We got totally sidetracked by this. I’m downvoting this answer because it doesn’t answer the question at all. The `as` operator has absolutely nothing to do with parsing strings into integers (or any other type). The other answer is much more relevant.