# Convert from String to type stored in Type variable

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm trying to do a kind of debug console in `Unity` to be able to change - for example - enable/disable `boolean` values at run-time.

There's a point where I have a value that I want to set in a certain variable but this value is stored as a `string` (input from the user) and I need to cast it to the type of that variable (stored in a `Type` variable) but I don't know if this is possible.

This is the part of my code where I have the problem:

```
private void SetValueInVariable(string variable, Type type, string toSet)
{
    //reflection - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection
    Type container = typeof(StaticDataContainer);
    FieldInfo placeToSet = container.GetField(variable, BindingFlags.Static);
    placeToSet.SetValue(null, //here I need to convert "toSet"); 
}
```

I would like to know if this is possible and how can I do it.

Comment: Don't name your variable `var`

Comment: @maccettura ...or `value`, for that matter :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight missed that one!

Comment: Edited. Thank you

Comment: @Magnetron: That's not the same question at all.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeDescriptor [provides a fairly robust way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648256/120955) to convert a string to a specific type. Of course, this will only work for a handful of types that have fairly straightforward parsing.

```
private void SetValueInVariable(string variable, Type type, string toSet)
{
    //reflection - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection
    Type container = typeof(StaticDataContainer);
    FieldInfo placeToSet = container.GetField(variable, BindingFlags.Static);
    var value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFrom(toSet);
    placeToSet.SetValue(null, value); 
}
```

Comment: OH Thank you! I'm just trying to convert to standard types so I suppose It would work.